# PHP Code MainUrl / Want to use HTTPS instead of HTTP

Tags: php, html, css

I have a php documents in which is used a MainUrl to get the url. The thing is that the main url is HTTP. Is there a way to change it to HTTPS? Thank you

Im using codes like this

```
<img src="<?php echo MAIN_URL; ?>/img/adv-img.png">
```

Comment: Because im getting "mixed content" error

Comment: You will get mixed content errors when you link to things with static http links... Use relative links for CSS, images, JS etc.. 
`<img src=" /dir/pic">`  NOT `<img src=" http://domain/dir/pic">`

Comment: Im using codes like this:      <img src="<?php echo MAIN_URL; ?>/img/adv-img.png">

Comment: Then change it to a relative URL like this: 
<img src="/img/adv-img.png">     I suspect MAIL_URL is a constant, and can not be altered. You could alternatively create a https var and use that instead.   $SMAIL_VAR='https://domain/'

Comment: Show us the code where `MAIN_URL` is defined please.  Is this a specific framework or something?

Comment: Or just link to anything, really using a `//dir/pic` link. Protocol neutral, works for any URL.

Comment: Use absolute urls with relative scheme. Relative urls can lead to errors (wrong url etc.). `//domain.com/res/file.png`

Comment: Well, you can change the main url to https, then you have HTTPS. All relative urls (incl. relative scheme) will use HTTPS then.